# Multithreaded Python application in background

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, plotly-dash

I have a Python application *myapp* on a Raspberry Pi, with a front end control panel made with [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/). I run the Dash app in its own thread so that I can use it to manipulate some settings inside *myapp*.

When I SSH in to the Raspberry Pi, I want to start the Python application *myapp* in the background and then close the remote shell window and just let it spin and do its thing. After having written this question I found I have to use [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) for this according to

```
nohup python path/to/myapp.py &
```

For other python apps just

```
python path/to/other_app &
```

seems to suffice.

So I guess I already have the answer to my question. But, while at the subject, is this the preferred and only solution?

Comment: I think you could use celery for a background task.

Comment: Try adding `signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIG_IGN)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on what specific linux variant you're running, but generally speaking the best way is to your let your system's service manager handle that. In most cases these days that means systemd.

Create a service config file-

```
[Unit]
Description=My Python Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/my/python/service.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

1. Put this in the `/lib/systemd/system/` with a name like `mypythonapp.service`.
2. Run `systemctl daemon-reload` so systemd knows to look for the new file.
3. Run `systemctl enable mypythonapp.service` to tell it to run the app on start.
4. Run `systemctl start mypythonapp.service` to tell it to run the app immediately.

Now your script will have logging, will restart when crashed or when the system reboots, and you don't have to manually kick it off.